# How do I stop my last grid item from overflowing?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm really stuck on this one. Everything seems to look right to me but clearly it isn't. When you resize down to about 800px the media query kicks in and sets the grid to be a 4 row / 3 column layout but the last grid item overflows outside of the document, why is this?

I suspect it's something to do with the nested container divs that parent the grid or something I've left out in the media query.?

I've included a js fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/uLwhxgto/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gurajada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Finger+Paint&family=Gurajada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  

        <title>The Best Shop For Clothes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav id="main-nav">
                <div class="nav-item-wrapper">
                    <h1 class="brand-name">SHOPCO</h1>
                    <div  class="nav-items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <li><a href="#">MEN'S</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <li><a href="#">WOMEN'S</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="main-container main-color-1">
            <div id="top-promo-wrapper">
                <img class="promo-image" src="images/promo-picture.jpg" alt="Image of promo">
                <!-- <button class="btn" class="promo-btn">Shop Now</button> -->
            </div>
            <div class="option-buttons-wrapper">
                <button class="btn" >MEN'S</button>
                <button class="btn" >WOMEN'S</button>
                <button class="btn" >HOODIES</button>
                <button class="btn" >SHOES</button>
            </div>

            <div class="image-grid">
                <div class="image-item">
                    <img class="summer-image"src="images/summer-girl-promo.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="image-item">
                    <img class="summer-image"src="images/summer-guy-promo.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /main-container-1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="color-bg-wrapper">
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="street-kid-grid">
                    <div class="sk-top-bar">
                        
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxHCKCt/street-kid-top-bar.jpg" alt="street-kid-top-bar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sk-image-panel sk-panel1">
                        <button class="btn style-btn">SHOP NOW</button> 
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Ps39JW/kicks.jpg" alt="shoes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sk-image-panel sk-panel2">
                        <button class="btn style-btn">SHOP NOW</button> 
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PCcg0S8/guy-hand-up.jpg" alt="fashion-man">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sk-image-panel sk-panel3">
                        <button class="btn style-btn">SHOP NOW</button> 
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hRFxBfZ/guy-style-jacket.jpg" alt="man in stylized jacket">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

'''

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Finger+Paint&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300&display=swap');


:root{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, Helvetica;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
}

#main-nav{
    background-color: #FFF1D0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 8rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;  
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.nav-item-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item-wrapper h1{
    flex-basis: 30rem;
    align-self: start;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: finger paint;
    flex: 0.5;
}

.nav-items{ 
    flex: 1;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 5%;

}

.nav-item-wrapper li{
    display: inline;
}

.nav-item-wrapper li:nth-child(odd){
    margin: 0 3%;
}

.nav-item-wrapper a{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

a{
    color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item-wrapper a:hover{
    color:rgb(52, 119, 206);
}

.main-container{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

#top-promo-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#top-promo-wrapper img{
    max-width: 100%
}


.promo-image{
    display: block;
}

#top-promo-wrapper button{
    top: 80vh;
    right: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #df1515 ;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: background-color 2s;
}

#top-promo-wrapper button:hover{
    background-color: #b91414;
    color: black;
}    

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.option-buttons-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 3%;
    justify-content: center;

}

.option-buttons-wrapper button{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 0.6rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(30, 120, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: width 2s;
    transition: background-color 200ms;
    transition: font-size 200ms;
}

.option-buttons-wrapper button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.image-grid{
    display: grid;
    margin: 20px 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2%;
}

.image-grid img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.color-bg-wrapper{
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

.street-kid-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "sk-top-bar sk-top-bar sk-top-bar"
    "sk-panel1  sk-panel2 sk-panel3";
    gap: 3%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sk-top-bar{
    grid-area: sk-top-bar;
}

.street-kid-grid img{
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.sk-panel1{
    grid-area: sk-panel1;
}

.sk-panel2{
    grid-area: sk-panel2;
}

.sk-panel3{
    grid-area: sk-panel3;
}

.sk-image-panel button{
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px){
    .option-buttons-wrapper button{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    .option-buttons-wrapper button:hover{
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
    .street-kid-grid{
        grid: 
            "sk-top-bar sk-top-bar sk-top-bar"
            ". sk-panel1 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel2 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel3 ." 1fr
            / 0 1fr 0;
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that since I had a 3 column layout [0 1fr 0], the 0 columns also got gap applied to them which was causing the image to overflow. Lowering the gap value fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yo man,

Listen I think I see what's the problem

Here is your css :

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px){
    .street-kid-grid{
        grid: 
            "sk-top-bar sk-top-bar sk-top-bar"
            ". sk-panel1 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel2 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel3 ." 1fr
            / 0 1fr 0;
    }
}
```

and here it's your Html :

```
 <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            ******<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">******
            <!-- Fonts -->
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gurajada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Finger+Paint&family=Gurajada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    
            <title>The Best Shop For Clothes</title>
        </head>
```

So the probleme I see if you look, is that you did not do seperated CSS files first, and in your head you've only declared

```
"<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">"
```

wich is missing the

```
" media="all and (max-width: 800px)" ".
```

so you have two choice : create 2 css files : one named "style.css" and one called "styleMax__800.css" and had both on 2 lines such as :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css"> *** normal***
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 800px) 
      href="css/styleMax__800.css">
```

or no, do it like that haha ^^

and I would advice you to add on both line

```
"type="text/css"
```

I've made that mistake so tell me if it solved your problem bro haha :)

all United.

Comment: This fixes my overflow issue?

Comment: Hopefully Yes :)

Comment: You see, as you did not declared your media in the <Head> of Html it wont work for 800px so if you declare it then at least it will be done and you'll see if it solve your problem but it would at least sho you afterward what did not work

Comment: So what do I put in the styleMax_800.css file?

Comment: @media all and (max-width: 800px){
    .street-kid-grid{
        grid: 
            "sk-top-bar sk-top-bar sk-top-bar"
            ". sk-panel1 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel2 ." 1fr
            ". sk-panel3 ." 1fr
            / 0 1fr 0;
    }